# How to configure Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have spring-integration-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" //etc. >

<channel id="inputChannel"/>

<channel id="outputChannel">
    <queue capacity="10"/>
</channel>

<service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
                   output-channel="outputChannel"
                   ref="gmailWorker"
                   method="getGmailMessage"/>

<beans:bean id="gmailWorker" class="GmailWorker"/>
```

Configuation:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-integration-config.xml")
public class PropertiesConfig {
}
```

And GmailWorker:

```
public class GmailWorker{
public static Message getGmailMessage(Gmail service,String messageId) throws IOException {
    Message gmailMessage = service.users().messages().get("me", messageId).execute();
    return gmailMessage;
}
}
```

Now I don't use InputChannel bean. But my application doesn't deployed on tomcat with logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0':
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Target object of type [class GmailWorker] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
```

How to configure Spring Integration? And how use `inputChannel` in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POJO method looks bad for Spring Integration runtime method invocation engine.

Any Spring Integration component gets deal with `Message` object, which has `headers` and `payload` properties.

When it invokes the POJO method it expects some restricted set of arguments on the method:

- Whole `Message`
- any other type which may be treated as `payload`, if there is some appropriate `converter` on the matter.
- `@Header` as the request for some header in the `MessageHeaders`
- `Map<String, Object> as whole set of`MessageHeaders`
- If you want get deal with `payload` and some headers you can mark params with `@Payload`, `@Headers` etc..

More info is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations).